# Selecting a model by name using Webservice.list on AzureML

Tags: python, azure, api, azure-machine-learning-service

I deployed a huggingface ML model on Azure and now I'm trying to select it using the Python SDK.

I'm trying this:

```
from azureml.core import Workspace, Webservice
mlw = Workspace.from_config("mlw.json")
services = Webservice.list(mlw)
services_filtered = Webservice.list(mlw, model_name=services[0].name)
```

Now, `services` is a list containing two models, but `services_filtered` is an empty list. What am I doing wrong here?

Of course, I could select the right one afterwards using the names, but that just doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out already. The name of the service is different from the name of the model. When using this, it does work:

```
services_filtered = Webservice.list(mlw, model_name=services[0].models[0].name)
```